# I can't remove comma after currency in commerce price

Tags: commerce

In my project I had to change currency code from USD to IRR (Iranian Rial)

but in Persian language after currency, there is always a "," character in rendered price (in price component or formatted amount).

Anyone knows how can we get rid from this comma.

[image: I've attached an image about this issue]

Comment: You didn't specify whether this is D7 or D8.

Comment: excuse me, I am using D7

Answer (score 0):

In `commerce.currency.inc` the currency is defined as:

```
'IRR' => array(
  'code' => 'IRR',
  'numeric_code' => '364',
  'symbol' => 'REMOVED_DUE_TO_SE_ERROR',
  'name' => t('Iranian Rial'),
  'symbol_placement' => 'before',
  'symbol_spacer' => ',',
  'code_placement' => 'hidden',
  'minor_unit' => t('Rial'),
  'major_unit' => t('Toman'),
  'decimals' => 0,
),
```

If you wanted to override this and set the `thousands_separator` (not present) to and empty string. You can do this in `hook_commerce_currency_info`, documented here http://cgit.drupalcode.org/commerce/tree/commerce.api.php?h=7.x-1.x#n11

You need to set it as, let's say `''` because the defaults are the following for missing properties:

```
  $defaults = array(
    'symbol' => '',
    'minor_unit' => '',
    'decimals' => 2,
    'rounding_step' => 0,
    'thousands_separator' => ',',
    'decimal_separator' => '.',
    'symbol_placement' => 'hidden',
    'symbol_spacer' => ' ',
    'code_placement' => 'after',
    'code_spacer' => ' ',
    'format_callback' => '',
    'conversion_callback' => '',
    'conversion_rate' => 1,
  );
```